# What risks does WebApi incur when calling Request.CreateResponse() inside await block?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, structuremap

I have an async WebApi controller that throws a StructureMapException when calling `Request.CreateResponse(HttStatusCode.Created, result)` inside an await block, but only during the first request. StructureMap resolves all the constructor dependencies properly but behaves as though `Request.CreateResponse` is called after the request ends. Is it simply a bad idea to use `Request.CreateResponse` inside an await block? What other risks might this strategy incur?

I'm using the following NuGet packages:

- StructureMap 3.1.6.186
- StructureMap.Web 3.1.0.133
- StructureMap.WebApi2 3.0.4.125
- WebActivator 2.0.5

Here is the code:

```
public class EmailController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ISaveEmailNotification _saveEmailNotification;
    private readonly ISaveFile _saveFile;

    public EmailController(ISaveEmailNotification saveEmailNotification, ISaveFile saveFile)
    {
        _saveEmailNotification = saveEmailNotification;
        _saveFile = saveFile;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SaveEmail(NotificationRequest model)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var emailResult = _saveEmailNotification.Execute(model);
            var fileResult = _saveFile.Execute(model, emailResult);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, fileResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
StructureMap.StructureMapException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233088
Message=You cannot use the HttpContextLifecycle outside of a web request. Try the HybridLifecycle instead.
1.) Container.GetInstance(System.Web.HttpContextBase)
2.) Container.TryGetInstance(System.Web.HttpContextBase)

Source=StructureMap.Web
Title=You cannot use the HttpContextLifecycle outside of a web request. Try the HybridLifecycle instead.
StackTrace:
   at StructureMap.Web.Pipeline.HttpContextLifecycle.findHttpDictionary() in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap.Web\Pipeline\HttpContextLifecycle.cs:line 57
   at StructureMap.Web.Pipeline.HttpContextLifecycle.FindCache(ILifecycleContext context) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap.Web\Pipeline\HttpContextLifecycle.cs:line 20
   at StructureMap.BuildSession.ResolveFromLifecycle(Type pluginType, Instance instance) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 102
   at StructureMap.SessionCache.GetObject(Type pluginType, Instance instance, ILifecycle lifecycle) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\SessionCache.cs:line 88
   at StructureMap.SessionCache.GetDefault(Type pluginType, IPipelineGraph pipelineGraph) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\SessionCache.cs:line 66
   at StructureMap.Container.GetInstance(Type pluginType) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:line 335
   at StructureMap.Container.TryGetInstance(Type pluginType) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:line 278
   at StructureMap.Container.TryGetInstance[T]() in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Container.cs:line 289
   at NotificationHubWeb.DependencyResolution.StructureMapDependencyScope.get_HttpContext() in C:\Users\Dave\Source\Workspaces\NotificationHub\Main\NotificationHubWeb\DependencyResolution\StructureMapDependencyScope.cs:line 68
   at NotificationHubWeb.DependencyResolution.StructureMapDependencyScope.get_CurrentNestedContainer() in C:\Users\Dave\Source\Workspaces\NotificationHub\Main\NotificationHubWeb\DependencyResolution\StructureMapDependencyScope.cs:line 55
   at NotificationHubWeb.DependencyResolution.StructureMapDependencyScope.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in C:\Users\Dave\Source\Workspaces\NotificationHub\Main\NotificationHubWeb\DependencyResolution\StructureMapDependencyScope.cs:line 109
   at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 49
```

Comment: Perhaps you want [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926728/using-structuremap-for-dependency-injection-to-signalr-2-0-1)

Comment: Not really a good fit. The error occurs in the StructureMapDependencyScope code provided by one of the nuget packages when the controller calls Request.CreateResponse, as if the per request container has already been cleaned up due to async issues. I worked around this by not calling Request.CreateResponse. Still strange that it only happens when Email.SaveEmail handles the first request sent to the web app. Never happens if I GET an empty page in a different controller first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using `Request.CreateResponse` outside the await block does side-step the StructureMapException on first-use when I rewrite the code thusly:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SaveEmail(NotificationRequest model)
{
    var taskResult await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var emailResult = _saveEmailNotification.Execute(model);
        return _saveFile.Execute(model, emailResult);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, taskResult);
}
```

Right now, this looks like the winner but I'll vote for or declare you the answerer if you can explain why moving `Request.CreateReponse` outside the await block allows the code to run without error.

Comment: hm interesting, I had a similar issue but because my awaitable code was not returning anything (just processing), I couldn't use this approach. Instead I've just used  `For<MyInterface>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(new MyClass());`

Comment: But I wasn't trying to use MyClass or any user code. Accessing the Request object on the controller throws the exception, so it has to do with how the controller and its Request property get instantiated by those Nuget packages. Everything is auto-registered.

Comment: try to have a look here (instead of HttpContext see if you can use HttpOrThread context) `NotificationHubWeb.DependencyResolution.StructureMapDependencyScope.get_HttpContext() in C:\Users\Dave\Source\Workspaces\NotificationHub\Main\NotificationHubWeb\DependencyResolution\StructureMapDependencyScope.cs:line 68`

Comment: I've read one of your above comments, that this is code coming from a nuget package, so I guess you just spotted a bug in their code :)